# Trigger error INSERT Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I tried to create trigger `AFTER UPDATE` via phpmyadmin with body INSERT:

```
BEGIN
INSERT INTO updatespersonal SET (user, time, type, operator) VALUES (NEW.idDetailToUsers, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), "detailtousers", "update");
END
```

But I get error, reason that I can not understand:

> ## 1064 on line 2

May be problem in double quotes?

Comment: share the error message

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Error in **Insert** Statement, remove **SET** keyword:

```
INSERT INTO updatespersonal (user, time, type, operator) VALUES (NEW.idDetailToUsers, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), "detailtousers", "update");
```

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is incorrect. You no need `SET` when using **[INSERT INTO](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp)**.

Your code should be:

```
BEGIN
INSERT INTO updatespersonal (user, time, type, operator) VALUES (NEW.idDetailToUsers, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), "detailtousers", "update");
END
```

Comment: Yea, you posted few seconds faster, because you posted only code with deleted word SET without description, while I wrote description why It not working and provided link to documentation.

Answer (score 0):

2 issues

1. In Insert INTO no need of SET
2. You are using a key word as column name user. enclose it in  ""

   `BEGIN
       INSERT INTO updatespersonal ("user", time, type, operator) VALUES (NEW.idDetailToUsers, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), "detailtousers", "update");
       END`